# React useEffect doesn't block the re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I need to create a functional react component that automatically update the inner data every time there is a particular event.

I written the code below, but every time the callback is called the component is re-rendered and the variable `myArray` is set to empty array instead to be filled with all content coming in the callback.

What am I doing wrong? What's the approach I should use?

```js
// event emulation
function onEventEmulator(callback, interval = 1000) {
    setInterval(() => callback('content'), interval);
}

function PollingComponent(props) {
    const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        onEventEmulator(content => {
            setMyArray([...myArray, content]);
        });
    }, []); // with or without passing the empty array as second param, result does not change.
    return <ul>
        <li>Callback</li>
        <li>{myArray.length}</li>
    </ul>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
function onEventEmulator(callback, interval = 1000) {
  setInterval(() => callback("content"), interval);
}
```

And then:

```
function PollingComponent(props) {
  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onEventEmulator(content => {
      setMyArray(arr => [...arr, ...content]);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>Callback</li>
      <li>{myArray.length}</li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

One thing that is missing here is a way to clear `setInterval`, but I guess that is not your concern here.

Comment: I miss here that this has to be done on some interval (not just once), will update the code shortely.

Comment: Are you looking for some event emitter approach or just polling from some api? If you are looking event emitter (which is more likely), than creating custom hook which uses global event emitter could be a solution. On another note if pooling is what you want there are hooks like this one https://github.com/vivek12345/react-polling-hook

Comment: First thanks for your help, I was trying this to study `useEffect`, and from its documentation should allow to change the state without re-render the component, but in my example it doesn't. Am I using useEffect in wrong way?

Comment: @Raffaele by looking at your code it's hard for me to say are you using `useEffect` correctly or not. Not sure what do you mean by "particular event" - is it some event like click on the button or somethig else (like subscription websocket subscription)? In other words, how `onEventEmulator` should fire? Can you create some example on https://codesandbox.io/ and I will do my best to look at it and help you as much as I can.

Comment: In regards to "changing state without re-render the component" (with useEffect and `setSomething` in useState hook, if that is what should be used to store component state) - that is a bit odd. Because every time we change component state, component must be re-rendered. It might be that you've missunderstood the docs.

1. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate : setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. This is the primary method you use to update ...

Comment: Thanks for the link to documentation but I'm not using the setState of classComponent but the useState and useEffect of hooks (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). My target is to have a DOM that automatically update when some new data is coming from some API. If the component is automatically re-render the state will be reset again and cannot keep track of old state.

Comment: `useState` update func works the same way as `setState` in class component. So, doc is relelevant - if you want to believe me. You should not be affraid that re-rendering will wipe-out old state because react uses closures to keep state in memory. When merging old data with new data you can use this format of updating the state: `setMyArray(arr => [...arr, ...newData])`. arr is your old state and newData would be data comming from api.

Comment: I tried to use it as you suggested `setMyArray(...myArray, newContent)` (as in first code I posted), but it doesn't work: every time I use it, because the component is re-render, all the method of the functional component is called, included the instruction `const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);` that will set again `myArray` to an empty array deleting whatever there was previously.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-ramanujan-9nt6y

Comment: Well that is not a form that I've suggested `setMyArray(...myArray, newContent)` is not the same as setMyArray(arr => [...arr, ...newData]). Here is how it might be implemented https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-hellman-u3g60

Comment: Thanks. now it's clear the difference and it works.

Comment: Hi @Danko, If I do it it looks the code you added is fixing the issue and it will create confusion to other user of the web site. I'll mark it as useful and accepted after you update your code in main answer.